# Flex 3 with Flash Player 10

Tags: windows, apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder, flash

I have just created a Flex 3 project. I understand from the flex-config file that the mininum requirement for Flex Builder 3 is Flash 9 or above.  I have Flash player 10 on my machine but when I launch my application in firefox. it gives the following error:

C:\Programs Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\plugins\NPSWF32.dll

Flex Builder cannot locate the required version of Flash Player. You might need to install Flash Player 9 or reinstall Flex Builder.

Do you want to try to run your application with the current version?

Can someone put some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually 3 Flash Players available ... be sure to have installed the correct one:
1. Standalone Player
2. ActiveX Player (Used in Internet Explorer)
3. Plugin Player (Used in allmost all other Browsers)

So if your Flex Builder for example opens the IE, then you have to have the Debug ActiveX

Comment: Thx chrisdutz..this was the root of the problem..

Thx..Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try to download proper **debug** flash player (content debugger) from [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)

Comment: Hello Chif,

This is what I did..I downloaded Flash 10 Debug version and installed it. It should normally work fine but it isn't.

Anyways thx for the suggestion.

Comment: Try upgrading your flash builder. Current version is 4.5.x and as i can suggest you are using 3.x. You still can use flex3, if you need.

Comment: Actually I have both versions on my machine. I have a rather complex project in Flex 3 which am planning to migrate to Flex 4. But the issue remain that..my Flex 3 project itself is not launching with Flash Player 10 (strange). When it starts working I can check things and do the migration gradually.